# Codeigniter calculate day, week, month, year from search 

Tags: codeigniter, date

I am developing a job site, and the custumer would like the following.
On the job submit, the user will be able to set a date when the actual job will start, and in the search there are the following options for job start to select:

```
<option value="">Today</option>
<option value="">Tomorrow</option>
<option value="">In a week</option>
<option value="">In a month</option>
```

And im a bit lost at this part, i never did something like this.
Now i dont want anybody to write this for me, just give me an advice or a hint, for the logic, if its posible.

What i donr really get is, what values should i give the options, and how to get the actual reasults if there is.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values only need to be ones you'll recognize when processing the request. They could be "today", "tomorrow", "next_week" and "next_month" if you want.

Then when handling the request, take today's date and add:

- nothing (today)
- one day (tomorrow)
- seven days (in a week)
- one month (in a month)

Look at [`DateTime::add`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) for the date arithmetic part.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add one thing only. 
Replace the value attribute of Option tag. For example
Today

Then handle the request through server. This is very nice logic to implement and its rather easy.